# sending form via AJAX as post - which is better content-type multipart/form-data or application/json

Tags: node.js, http-post, content-type

Environment - server is node.js with express and appropriate modules.

I know how to send data using both methods (as multipart/form-data and also application/json).

For simple form submissions with no file uploads or such, I find it a bit cumbersome to send data using multipart/form-data and would prefer to keep using application/json for my POST requests.

Is there any reason why I should choose to send forms as multipart/form-data over application/json if there is no file upload involved ?

i.e. if it is more secure or has some data security benefit ?

Answer (score 0):

application/json is better for this case.